# Excel - Unstack Data via String Identifier

Tags: excel

I've used the `ctrl` + `shift` select all & copy as path to grab the names of all files (images) in a folder and put them into an excel sheet.

This gives me a result set like:

```
ColA
1001 (0).jpg
1001 (1).jpg
1001 (2).jpg
1002 (0).jpg
1002 (1).jpg
1003 (1).jpg
1003 (2).jpg
```

I'd like to move the data like this:

```
ColA         | ColB         | ColC
1001 (0).jpg | 1001 (1).jpg | 1001 (2).jpg
1002 (0).jpg | 1002 (1).jpg
             | 1003 (1).jpg | 1003 (2).jpg
```

What kind of formula could I use to achieve this? As some files have versions (0), (1), (2), (3), (4) but not always?

Comment: Check [Power Query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) and the pivot/unpivot feature

Comment: @RicardoDiaz i'll check it out thanks.

Comment: Do you have any recommendation as to how to do this with the pt pivot feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with formulas, honestly.

In column b type out the 1001, 1002, 1003 (or type out the 1001 & 1002, highlight both, and drag down and it should auto populate for you.

Then use these formulas in columns c, d, & e, respectively.

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(B2&" (0).jpg",$A$2:$A$8,0)),"")`
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(B2&" (1).jpg",$A$2:$A$8,0)),"")`
`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(B2&" (2).jpg",$A$2:$A$8,0)),"")`

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Hooded 0ne